# Stop page refreshing in NavigationUI, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Development. There a weird error, whenever I am trying to change the fragment, the content is loading each time . I am making a API request from the First Fragment, and the request is taking placed each single time.

I am not sure where the error is

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityBottomTabBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_bottom_tab);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }
```

Above is the code for bottom tabs.

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        listView = binding.mobileList;
        cryptoList = new ArrayList<String>();
        loadCoinList();
        return root;
    }
```

And this is the code for `first fragment`.

Comment: So you mean whenever you are returning to first fragment , the content is loading again ?

Comment: Yes exactly, Is there any way to like restore the previous state?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because everytime you switch fragments , the fragment gets destroyed and recreated calling your methods in onCreateView again. That's how bottomNavigation works.

If you want to retain the data, you can use viewModels.
Here take a look : [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Viewmodels are easy to use and you can also retain data on configuration changes like screen rotation